# Retrieving a URL though an authenticating proxy using PHP

Tags: php, proxy

I am attempting to script the retrieval of an secure (password protected + https) URL trough a proxy server that requires authentication. I found many examples of how to use the 'proxy' option and how to send credentials with stream_context_create.

```
$url = "https://$server/$uri";
$cred = sprintf('Authorization: Basic %s\r\n', base64_encode("$user:$pass"));
$options['header']=$cred;
$options['proxy']="tcp://10.1.1.1:3128";
$params = array('http' => $options);
$ctx = stream_context_create($params);
$fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
```

However I did not find any where a uid/password was provided to the proxy server.  I attempted to add a header manually:

```
$prox_cred = sprintf('Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive\r\nProxy-Authorization: Basic %s\r\n', base64_encode("$proxy_user:$proxy_pass"));
$options['header'] .= $prox_cred;
```

I have root access to the proxy server and I can see my request hitting it, but when I look into the traffic I don't see my headers.  I guess they are being added to the portion that gets encrypted and sent to the end server.

Comment: Not sure if this will fix it, but change your sprintf to `$cred = sprintf("Authorization: Basic %s\r\n", base64_encode("$user:$pass"));`  The CRLF sequence isn't being evaluated because you used single quotes.  You are actually getting `\r\n` as a part of your string.  Also, any reason you don't/cant use cURL for this?  It supports authorization and proxy.

Comment: Are you able to make the proxy credentials work using curl? If you can get that working then at least you know the proxy is working with your credentials (before you dig deeper with the headers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I didn't want to complicate things by using the cURL modules for the first time.  However based on the responses I tried it and it took about 6 minutes to get things working.

```
if ($proxy_server != '') {
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH,CURLAUTH_BASIC);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXY,"$proxy_server");
  if ($proxy_user != '') {
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH,CURLAUTH_BASIC);
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD,"$proxy_user:$proxy_pass");
  }  
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not bad form, and having this posted may help future users. Please consider clicking the checkmark next to this answer to alert others that it work.